# Pass the ISP DNS to your DHCP clients on OpenWRT

Tags: router, dns, dhcp, openwrt, dnsmasq

Basically I need my DCHP clients to have their DNS pointing to the ISP ones rather than pointing to the OpenWRT/Router's IP.

On (latest) DD-WRT, you can check the option to disable DNSMasq local DNS, letting DHCP pass the DNS from the WAN/ISP Modem DHCP. Here I'm kind of lost in the woods.

**Update 1:** After a brief DNS Benchmark [suggested by Frank Thomas](https://superuser.com/questions/1016880/pass-the-isp-dns-to-your-dhcp-clients-on-openwrt#comment1411506_1016880), the software pointed that DNSMasq's DNS Server worked very well. It seems I'm gonna stick to this, as the Local DNS Server resolves their queries asking directly to the ISP DNS (they are saved in the `/tmp/resolv.conf.auto` file), until some major problem arises.

After some days investigating my issue, it seems that DNSMasq in OpenWRT (15.05) doesn't allow to dynamically push the DNS Servers of your ISP. You have to write them manually.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the OpenWRT approach, but on most systems that provide DHCP and DNS Masquerading, you still have to provide a DNS server address to the DHCP server, to pass out. it will not automatically take the WANs DNS server and pass it to clients. Just observe what DNS server the router's WAN pulls from the ISP DHCP, and put it into your DHCP instance to pass out to clients.

Comment: Yes, I'm kind of aware of that. It seems that the only option is to write them manually, and hope it won't change forever, or try to get the values from ´/tmb/resolv.conf.auto´ and add them automatically to `/etc/config/dnsmasq` as DNS servers though OpenWRT's UCI... if there is a command or something.

Comment: do you have to use the ISP servers? I generally find better DNS servers for my location/connection with the GRC DNS benchmarking utility, and they have static addresses, so you can set/forget. https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: Not, but usually when using things like YouTube TV Connect or Chromecast, my devices tend go AWOL. When I used my ISP DNS directly on DHCP, the problem went away.